# Chrome Developer Tools: Show Associated Browser Tab?

Tags: google-chrome

I often have many (many!) browser tabs open in Chrome. Often times I'll have a developer tools window open but lose track of the associated browser tab.

Is there a keyboard shortcut or menu or button somewhere that will bring the associated tab (and browser window) to the forefront?

Answer (score 1):

UPDATE:  Just noticed that **the shortcut key is F12**.  It's listed against a "Focus debuggee" menu option under the vertical ellipsis.  (Chrome 66.)

Original answer:

I was just looking for a similar shortcut.
I haven't found one, but if you go to the console in your developer tools window and run a quick

```
window.alert()
```

then it looks like the associated main window+tab is brought to the front to display the popup, and it remains there when the popup is dismissed.
(That's what I'm seeing as of Chrome 60.)

Comment: ... and by Chrome 64 I'm no longer seeing this.  Now the alert shows up when you manually switch back to the appropriate tab.   Gotta love progress!

Answer (score 0):

1. In devtools click the top right cogwheel to open **Settings**

[image]

2. Click **Shortcuts** in the left navigation menu, and scroll down until you see **Focus debugee**. You'll see the shortcut key that is assigned with an option to modify it, or an option to set the shortcut if not defined.

[image]

<sup>NOTE: In some versions of chrome the option might be called <kbd>Focus page</kbd></sup>